# how to host .net 4 Windows Forms controls in HTML

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, controls

I have a windows forms application which uses a WSDualHttpBinding wcf service. What I want to do is, display this application on web. I am able to display windows forms application controls at a html page. To do this, I compiled project with .net 2.0 and checked project assembly properties to make it visible for COM access. With this setup everything works but i can not access my wcf service. Because project is framework 2.0 i can not add service reference. Only possibility is to add web reference (old style web service) which is not possibly for current situation.

So what do you suggest me to do?

1- I can make my wcf service somehow reachable for .net 2.0 applications
2- I can make my controls library work at browser with .net 4.0
3- another solution

Comment: Are you asking whether you can put a Windows Forms control (as in, user interface control like a textbox) in a web page?  If you are, this is not possible.

Comment: @DanPuzey no it is possible with the way described in this link http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx

Comment: Yeesh, that's about the most horrible thing I've ever seen.  I assume you realise this is not cross-browser?

Comment: @DanPuzey yes i agree it is very horrible, i feel like i will end up using silverlight. but i will force this solution a bit more. Because switching to silverlight will make me build every ui elements again...

Comment: Why on Earth are you targeting such an ancient .NET version?  Just target 3.0 or higher and be done with it.  Although you really ought to target 4 to take advantage of its CLR version isolation feature.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't do a dual HTTP binding with .NET 2.0. It only can use SOAP web services.
2. You would have to write an ActiveX control to host it, but it would not be cross browser.

Comment: I have also problems with writing activex controls. So I changed my way to windows forms controls.